# Rotating a map/projection in GeoPandas

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, rotate

I'm trying to get a map of Manhattan that is aligned vertically. I have a GeoJSON file with polygons in EPSG:4326 in `fname` that I've been transforming to [EPSG:6539](https://epsg.io/6539)

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(fname).to_crs("EPSG:6539")
```

Everything works as intended, but I would really like something like [this example](https://scalablemaps.com/map/newyork-manhattan-vert-bw-nolabels):
[image: Vertical map of manhattan]

Is there a named transform that accomplishes this? If not, how to correctly rotate the whole CRS in GeoPandas? If I do something like `gdf.rotate(28)`, I get each polygon rotated individually but not the whole map rotated, like so:

[image: bad rotation result]

Comment: If the rotate doesn't have a pivot point, you'll need to compute the translation values and shift individual geometries on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rotate` method has an `origin` parameter. By default it used the center of each geometry individually, but you can also pass a single point so that the same origin is used for all geometries.

Using the New York borough boundaries as examples:

```py
df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
# the default rotates each geometry individually
df_rotated1 = df.rotate(28)
```

[image]

Passing a single point as rotation origin (here I am taking the centroid of the unary union, but you could also calculate the center of the bounding box much more cheaply based on `df.total_bounds` if you prefer, a the unary union can be quite expensive):

```py
df_rotated2 = df.rotate(28, origin=df.unary_union.centroid)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I want to be able to rotate it back, I'll have to use the centroid or save the origin, because the bbox origin will shift around.

Comment: This rotates the geometries, not the map. It works in this simple example because there is no context, but any other layers e.g. a basemap would now be misaligned.